# Apache url rewrite not working

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Currently I can access my url in this way.

```
xxxxxx.com/index.php/login
```

But I want to make it to

```
xxxxxx.com/login
```

So I used the following rewrite sequence

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

But xxxxxx.com/login is giving me 404 Not found.

rewrite.load is present in mods-enabled/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you use .htaccess file? please check AllowOverride directive in a Vhost configuration, should be: AllowOverride All.

Answer (score 0):

Replace AllowOverride None by AllowOverride in /etc/apache2/sites-available/default .htaccess fils not read by apache, because it's configuration files weren't allowing an htaccess to override previoulsy given instructions.